# Hide/Collapse the MdiClient area

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an MDIParent form setup with some docked controls, which leaves the MdiClient area on the right of the window. What I'd like is that when there are no MdiChildren, this pane is hidden. But no amount of docking or show/hide can get it to work.

I'm reluctant to fallback to calculating the size of another control so it overlaps this space when empty. Is there a smarter way?

Comment: You just want to make the control hidden when there are no MdiChildren right? Why simply set pane.Visibility = false..

Comment: The MdiClient control is parented directly on the form, and hiding that control just leaves an empty space the same size. The docked controls don't adjust their position. Can I perhaps manually add an MdiClient instance to my form, so that I can host it in a panel or something...?

Comment: Try this tutorial out and see if it helps [Collapsible Forms made easy with WinForms, Layout Panels and AutoSize](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cumgranosalis/archive/2006/05/18/collapisbleforms.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this is a massive existing codebase, and I can't overhaul the visual layout. I can only adjust it. After all my investigation, I think the combination of MdiContainer and other 3rd party controls means I am a bit stuck on this issue. Can't re-parent the MdiClient, and the 3rd party controls have odd side-effects from some settings.